# Copy Spreadsheet file (only visible sheets)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to copy only the visible sheets of a Spreadsheet File with .copy()?

```
destination = ss.copy(destName);
```

This is the copy of the file, right now I'm making the copy and iterating the copy sheets to delete hidden sheets, but I think it would be better if I could directly make the copy without hidden sheets (not deleting sheets in the original file obviously).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function copyvis() {
  const  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dssid);
  ss.getSheets().filter(sh => !sh.isSheetHidden()).forEach(sh => sh.copyTo(dss));
}
```